# Football: final score when one team gets 5 players sent off?

Tags: rules, football

What becomes the final score if 5 players gets sent off from one team?

In the video game FIFA the opposing team wins with 3-0. However, if one team leads by more, say 6-0, will this be the final score? Would be unfair otherwise